# How to make SQL Server find a login matching the name provided?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, sql-server-express

I have just restored a database backup to my local SQL Server express instance.

1. In management studio under the server instance node I went to: Security -> Logins -> New login...
2. Then I filled in a login name, password and chose SQL Server authentication. And at the bottom I selected the newly restored database to be the Default database.
3. At the User Mapping 'tab' at the left, I mapped the user to the newly restored database and gave it "db_owner" role.

When I try to login the following error is given in the log:

> Login failed for user 'username'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: ]

**How can I make SQL Server find the login matching the name I provided?**

Other info:

- Named pipes are enabled
- TCP/IP is enabled
- Remote connections are allowed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please make sure you have selected "SQL Server Authentication" mode for user you created from 
Server > Security > Logins option.

Another possibility, is that you created the SQL Server login using Management Studio, and the option requiring the user to change the password on first login was checked. If you didn't immediately login with Management Studio, and change the password, then the attempt to login from the other machine is not able to pop up a dialog box to change the password and so it fails.

try it by removing user and create again.

Comment: I did both... SQL Server authentication was selected and I did **NOT** check the enforce password policy checkbox.

Comment: it worked for me, i scripted out to create the user and deleted the user and ran the script to create the user again and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is old but for some one who encounters error for ASP.Net Core 2.2 using EF core and VS Code, I got error

> Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
>   Login failed for user 'sa:password=MyPassword'.

I looked logs from SSMS and found error as

> Login failed for user 'sa:password=MyPassowrd'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: MyIp]

After searching here and there i found that I have to add **Persist Security Info=False** in connection string, so my connection string became like

> "Default":"Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Server=MyServerIp"

I found this format from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax). After that it worked fine.

persist security info=false is default. I didnot found any reason why my connection string without it was not working. [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419627/persist-security-info-property-true-and-persist-security-info-property-false)