# Persist Security Info Property=true and Persist Security Info Property=false

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

For the properties:

```
Persist Security Info=true
```

and

```
Persist Security Info=false
```

Can you tell me what is the difference between them, and if I don't put it in my connection what will happen?

```
connect.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                            Data Source=C:/Users/Nourah/Downloads 
                            /Phase3/Salary.accdb; 
                            Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differance Between Persist Security Info And Integrated Security](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009976/differance-between-persist-security-info-and-integrated-security)

Comment: but i don't understand carefully when i applied on code , same result

Comment: Not sure there is any point in using Persist Security Info with ms-access

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Even if you set `Persist Security Info=true` OR `Persist Security Info=false`
it won't show a difference up front. The difference is happening in the background.

When `Persist Security Info=False`, security-sensitive
information, such as the password, is not returned as part of the
connection if the connection is open or has ever been in an open
state.

If you set `Persist Security Info=True`, Windows will remember the password specified in the connection string.

That's the difference.

[MSDN Explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Setting `Persist Security Info` true or false will come into effect only if you mention username and password in the connection string. If you mention username and password in the connection string and set `Persist Security Info` as `false` then the credentials cannot be extracted, but if you set `Persist Security Info` as true while giving credentials in the connection string, windows will remember the credentials, and it can be extracted programmatically.

Comment: so if i want set it to true how i will write the connection code ??

Comment: @Nourah setting it true or false will come into efffect only if you mention username and password in connection string..If you mention username and password in connectionstring and set this as false then the credentials cannot be extracted..but if you set to true while giving credentials in the connectionstring windows will remember the credentials and it can extracted in pgm...see edited answer

Comment: "then the credentials cannot be extracted.."  By what, the source code? What are pro's and con's and a simple scenario of when someone would need to set this to true?

Comment: What does pgm mean?

Comment: @sotn sorry i meant it as program

Comment: @eaglei22, A user of .net entity framework's DbContext might want to extract the connection string in order to create additional connections for use in lower level operations such as SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: @Chris Exactly this. You want to get the connection string from the EF DbContext to use for some non-EF DB operation like SqlBulkCopy or you want to get data from a raw SQL query without creating a POCO to read it into (as far as I know EF Core doesn't allow executing raw SQL into an `object`). I wonder though if using Persist Security Info = True poses a security risk and if making the connection string available via the options pattern would be safer. I don't see how it would but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 32):

I found this answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bb97cafd-d3aa-450a-ad33-f8e450c8a7b3/persist-security-info?forum=sqldataaccess) from Dan Guzman, SQL Server MVP:

> I suggest you specify FALSE or omit the keyword entirely since it is
>   the default, even during development.  The only time you need to
>   specify TRUE is if the application uses SQL authentication and
>   subsequently retrieves the password from the connection object, which
>   in my experience is rarely done or needed.  Performance is not a
>   concern.