# why contained database user needs Persist Security Info=True

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I have a database where I created a contained user and I needed to connect to my web app using that user. I have always been able to connect to the web app with a standard user having `Persist Security Info=False`.

However, the only way I was able to connect with the contained user was changing my connection string to `Persist Security Info=True`, otherwise I'd get a login failed sql exception even though I was able to connect using SSMS. I'm not sure why it worked, does anybody know why a contained user needs the property set to True?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419627/persist-security-info-property-true-and-persist-security-info-property-false

Comment: This question helped us fix our connection string so we could connect to Azure with a contained user.

Answer (score 9):

For you web app, are you using Entity Framework ?
And for your DbContext are you using `IdentityDbContext` ?

If so, I had the same problem. I was able to connect directly with SqlConnection but encountered an "Access Deny" error when connecting with Entity Framework.
When I gave enough permissions to my user, all queries were very slow.

When instantiating the Context (with `IdentityDbContext`) you should set the second parameter to false.

```
public AdeleDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, false)
{
}
```

The second parameter is `throwIfV1Schema` and when set to `true` (which is the default value), it will validate schema against the database by calling `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=@Table` for many columns.

That was the reason why the connection was slow and user needed more permissions when connecting to DB with Entity Framework and IdentityDbContext.