# EntityFramework - Problems with login into database when using a console application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, app-config

```
public class FoobarContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IFoobarContext
{
    public FoobarContext() : base("connectionStringNameFoobar") {...}
    ...
}
```

This is my DbContext I am using in my solution.
I have a web application, which at some point accesses the context and it can successfully connect and login to my database.

Now I have also added a console application to my solution. It uses the same code. It tries to initialize the same Context. **But when I run my console application, I get the exception that the user cannot login because the provided password is wrong.**

Here is also the sql server log "Login failed for user 'FooBarUser'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: local machine]"

Here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="connectionStringNameFoobar" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyFoobarDB;User Id=FooBarUser;Password=FooBar123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I enter the connection string directly it does not works either. e.g.:

```
public FoobarContext() : base("data source=localhost;initial catalog=MyFoobarDB;User Id=FooBarUser;Password=FooBar123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework") {...}
```

The strange thing is that when I use an overload for IdentityDbContext ctor and pass an existing SqlConnection, it works. e.g.:

```
public FoobarContext () : base(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringNameFoobar"].ConnectionString), true)
```

Note that I have also tried passing the connection string via the configuration manager as seen above and not using the overload, where I pass a SqlConnection but that resulted in the same login error.

Additionally:

- I have checked my connection strings several times. They are identical in my web app and in my console app.
- I have checked them with another colleague.
- I have checked that the connection string gets resolved correctly
- I can login manually into the db (through management studio) when using the credentials from the connection string

My Setup:

- .NetFramework 4.6.1
- EntityFramework 6.1.3 (but I have also tried it
  with 6.2.0
- Autofac 3.5.2

In each case (web app & console app) the FoobarContext is instantiated via Autofac.

So this begs the question: Why?

EDIT:
passing the connection string directly also DOES NOT work. My bad

Comment: Can you login with same user and password through management studio?

Comment: @JoelHarkes yes I can

Comment: in the config, is the `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` set on the connection string?

Comment: @MartinUllrich yes, in both configs. Please see "Here is my connection string:"

Answer (score 1):

Including "Persist Security Info=true" in my connection string fixed my problem.

For further information, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30420514/3827069

Although I have read that it is not recommended to set it to true. So a better solution is always welcome